# Get a field based on an attribute with jq

Tags: json, jq

Let's say that I have the following structure:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "wrapper_1": {
            "attr1": "val1",
            "attr2": "val2",
            "attr3": true
        }
    },
    {
        "wrapper_2": {
            "attr1": "val1",
            "attr2": "val2",
            "attr3": false
        }
    },
    {
        "wrapper_3": {
            "attr1": "val1",
            "attr2": "val2",
            "attr3": false
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

}

As you can see, I have an array that, for some reason, has a set of objects that have a different "title" (wrapper), but its inside structure is shared by all the elements present into that array.
I'll have on `attr3` only one truthy element, while the rest of the elements of `data` will have a `false` value on that element.

Given that condition (`attr3 == true`), I need to filter that element and get the value of `attr2`. I am a beginner with jq and I tried this with no luck:

`jq '.path.to.data[] | select(.attr3 == true)'`

I'm reading about the combination of `map` and `select` but I can't figure it out. Also, I know that the snippet above doesn't work because it assumes that elements of `data` are homogeneous and this is not the case.

Any advice about this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data, the filter:

```
.data[][] | select(.attr3) | .attr2
```

produces:

```
"val2"
```

Comment: That was it! One last question: what does it mean the double bracket syntax `[][]`? I can't find that in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: .[][] is just a shorthand for .[] | .[] -- and in general `EXP[]` is shorthand for `EXP | .[]` so potentially one can string many of them together. The less obvious point here, perhaps, is that .[] can be used on JSON objects.

Comment: That was my exact confusion: using the bracket syntax twice when there's only one array there. Thank you for your help!